# Can I export a list of downloaded iPhone apps from iTunes?

Tags: itunes, windows, itunes-store

I have a long list of apps I've downloaded for my iPhone on a single PC. I would like to export a list of these apps to a text format.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second answer concerns Mac OS X (as I haven't specified the system when asking the question). Here is the **answer for Windows** (tested on Windows XP SP2):

Open cmd.exe by clicking *Start menu --> Run*, then type `cmd` and click `<Enter>`. Type:

```
cd C:\Documents and Settings\<your_user_name>\My documents\My musc\iTunes\iTunes Media\Mobile Applications\
```

Then you execute the following command (to get the list of files in this directory without extensions):

```
For %a in (*.*) do @echo %~na >> AppsList.txt
```

You'll have the full list of apps (ordered alphabetically ascending by default) in the 'AppsList.txt' file.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a few Terminal commands.

First, open the Terminal by going to Applications -> Utilities -> Terminal.  Then, paste in the following and press <kbd>return</kbd>.

```
cd ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Mobile\ Applications
```

Then, paste in this next command and press <kbd>return</kbd>.

```
ls > ~/my_apps.txt
```

Now, in your Home folder (/Users/*yourusername*/), there will be a text file called my_apps.txt containing a list of all of your apps.

Comment: From the question I would assume @REACHUS is using a PC. Besides that, a directory listing of the .ipa files doesn't contain a lot of information.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need to do it on Windows :). I've added my own answer with Windows explanation.

Comment: Oh well, that's fine :).  Based on your answer, the Windows and Mac approaches are not much different.